How do we write the potential difference between the final and initial points?
If you want to find the potential difference between point A and point B, the potential difference is written:
$$ V_{ab}= V_{a} - V_{b} $$
or
$$ V_{ab}= V_{b} - V_{a} $$
AND is work the same thing?
I got confused because I see that some people write it with the first picture and some with the second picture

I am afraid that there is no absolute consensus and so you will continue to be confused until you see an author's statement of the convention used. The same is also true of forces.

Are you confused about the subscripts $V_{ab}$ vs $V_{ba}$ to refer to $V_b-V_a$, or are you confused about whether you should use $V_b-V_a$ vs $V_a-v_b$? One can completely clear this up by using $f$ and $i$ (for final and initial points), and using a subscript that makes the direction clear. For instance, $\Delta V_{i\to f} = V_f-V_i$ or $\Delta V_{f\leftarrow i} = V_f-V_i$.

@march , $ V_{a \rightarrow  b} = V_{ab} $ are the same? or Inverses، Does the expression differ when an arrow is placed?

I confused about the subscripts

As already pointed out there appears to be no absolute consensus on which is used (though personally I’ve seen the first equation more often).
In any case, the magnitude of the potential difference is the same for both equations, but with an opposite sign (+ or -) depending on which point (a or b) is at the higher potential.
Hope this helps.

Certainly, both notations are utilized. The outcome remains identical; one must simply exercise caution regarding the symbols preceding the potential.
